# How can I view/check all alt texts in my PDF file?

Tags: pdf, viewers, acmart, accessibility, software

I wrote a paper using the acmart class and took care to write meaningful alt texts using its `\Description` command. However, I want to check whether they got compiled correctly, as I am not sure how they are preprocessed with regard to special characters, linebreaks, etc. Unfortunately, I am not aware of any free/non-install software that is able to display these alt texts to me. I don't own Acrobat Reader or something similar. Chrome and Edge seem not to provide access to this information.

Can you recommend to me any free software or even better, online services, that can extract all alt texts?

**Edit:** Here is a MWE I would like to check:

```
\documentclass{acmart}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=3cm,height=2cm]{example-image-a}
\Description{This is the alt text for the first image in this document.

    The alt text contains multiple paragraphs, speßi"al characters, ``text inside quotes`', and also s\$ev&r=l t_ypograph^ic ch\%racters.}

\end{document}
```

Comment: show a small, complete example that can be used for a check.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Of course, sorry, I added an MWE to the question.

Comment: well the command currently ignores its argument and only sets a boolean.  It seems to have been added in preparation of tagging:  https://github.com/borisveytsman/acmart/issues/458. Regarding the content, I would say, if your text works reasonably well in the bookmarks (test it in a heading) then it will work also as alt text.